# MVC Table CRUD with Inline Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I have this table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th style="width: 20px">Actions</th>
    </tr>@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationID)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationName)</td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action(" Edit ", new { id = item.LocationID})">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
            </a>
            <a href="@Url.Action(" Delete ", new { id = item.LocationID})">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i>
                <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
            </a>

        </td>
    </tr>}
    <tr>
        <td><i class="glyphicon-plus"></i>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the edit, delete, and add buttons are all working but they are taking me into a new page to perform the edit, add and delete. Is it possible that when I click the edit, the corresponding row becomes editable and edit button become save button to post/save it to database? Can anyone show me how its done or point me where I can see some example pls im new to web development.

Comment: Why don't you use **JqGrid**?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you're after.  My preferred method is to use a dialog for new/edit rather than inline, but I've used inline plenty of times.  It depends on how many inputs there are - if just LocationName then inline is fine.

One simple method is to include the editor on the view, then show/hide it as required.

Change this:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationName)</td>
```

to:

```
<td>
    <div class='inline-view'>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationName)
    </div>
    <div class='inline-edit' style='display:none;'>
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.LocationName)
    </div>
</td>
```

and change the edit button to call some javascript

```
<div class='inline-view'>
    <a href='#' onclick='startEdit();return false;'>edit</a> 
</div>
<div class='inline-edit' style='display:none;'>
    <a href='#' onclick='cancelEdit();return false;'>cancel</a>
</div>
```

(of course, be a purist and add the click event via javascript, for illustrative purpose only)
You also don't need all the div's - just added for clarity.

then add some js:

```
function startEdit() {
    // you could use fadeOut/fadeIn or slide etc to make it a bit nicer here
    // maybe flash the background of the input to show something's changed
    // etc
    $(".inline-view").hide();
    $(".inline-edit").show();
}

function cancelEdit() {
    $(".inline-edit").hide();
    $(".inline-view").show();
}
```

(again, production code should use proper namespaces)

You'll then need to post the edit - add a small save button next to the EditorFor and either use Ajax to post or add `<form>` tags.

An alternative approach is to load the inline form when the edit button is clicked - create a PartialView for the edit form and use an ajax call to load it in and replace the existing table row/cell - on save, load a PartialView for the view part and overwrite.  The ajax approach ensures you're editing up-to-date data, but is a little more complicated.